# Git command to unstage all new files (unstage by status)

Tags: git

Often after a merge operation between branches I find in the stage area several new files that I don't want to have by default in the stage, but rather I would want to have by default unstaged to check them and stage them one by one after a review .

So the question is : ***is it possible to unstage all new files automatically ?***

or more generally : ***is it possible to unstage a group of files by their status ?***

For example I have this contents in the staging area :

```
A   fileA.txt
A   fileB.txt
U   fileC.txt
```

I want to remove the newly added files (`fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt`) in a single command, without performing git reset on each of them by hand :

```
git reset HEAD fileA.txt
git reset HEAD fileB.txt
```

What is the best way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I searched on the web with no luck, I've created a git alias using the following concatenated set of commands from the git bash shell :

```
git diff --name-status --cached | grep ^A | sed 's/^A[[:space:]]//g' | xargs -I {} git reset HEAD {}
```

The alias(unstagenew) definition is as follows :

```
[alias]
    unstagenew = "!sh -c 'git diff --name-status --cached | grep ^A | sed 's/^A[[:space:]]//g' | xargs -I {} git reset HEAD {}'"
```

To adapt to other status just replace the regex : `^A` with : `^M`, `^D`, `^U` ...

While to avoid the cumbersome output put `> /dev/null` at the end of the command .

I hope in the future it will be implemented as an option to the reset command, or as a new built in git command .

Comment: How about `git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD -z | xargs -r -0 git reset HEAD` instead?  This avoids the ugly `grep` and `sed` calls, and separates the files by NUL characters, so it works on any file name (i.e. even file names that contain newline characters).